# Is there a way of getting a number to increment by 1 each time when inside a while loop?

Tags: php, html

I have this function:

```php
function newMessages() {
    global $connection;

    $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toUserId = '$userId' && messageRead = 'No' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
    $selectImageQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirmQuery($selectImageQuery);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectImageQuery)) {
        $messageId = escape($row['messageId']);
        $message =  escape($row['message']);
        $fromUsername = escape($row['fromUsername']);
        $username = escape($_SESSION['username']);
        $date = escape($row['date']);
        $time = escape($row['time']);

        $query = "SELECT messageCount FROM users WHERE userId = '$userId' ";
        $selectCountQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirmQuery($selectCountQuery);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectCountQuery)) {
            $messageCount = escape($row['messageCount']);

            for ($i = 1; $i<=$messageCount; $i++) {
                $messageCount = $i;
                echo $messageCount;

                echo "
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo$messageCount'>$date / $time - 1 new message from $fromUsername</button>
          <div id='demo$messageCount' class='collapse'>
            $message 
          </div><br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first while loop checks for messages and echo's them out which it does. I then need to find a way where a user can click on each one and only see the info for that one. Currently when a user clicks on one they all open because the data-target (of course) is the same for each. So i am thinking if there is a way of having $messageCount change on each loop

Please help!!! I am going mad

If i change `for($i = 1; $i<=$messageCount; $i++)` for `for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)` then i get 10 of the 1st message, then 10 of the 2nd message and so on. However only all the 1's open so it's a start i guess.

[image]

It would be nice if the number (down the left) went from 1 - 4

Comment: what about using messageId?

Comment: You SIR are a flipping legend!!!! I have spent all day on this going mad getting lost inside loops!!! How did I not see this??

Comment: Hi @Dharman thank you. Yeah i realise this, I will change this to a prepared statement, its just for now I wanted to get it working 1st and then I will change this

Answer (score 0):

I reckon I have managed to solve your problem. The problem lies in the last `for-loop`:

```php
$messageCount = escape($row['messageCount']);

            for ($i = 1; $i<=$messageCount; $i++) {
                $messageCount = $i;
                echo $messageCount;
                ...
}
```

Here you first get `$messageCount`. For this example it becomes `4`. Then in the loop, `$i` becomes `1`. Inside the loop you set `$messageCount` equal to `$i`, which was `1`. In the next "loop round" you check whether `$i` is lower or equal to `$messageCount`. Because both are now `1`. The loop continues.

You can solve this by replacing the above for-loop with the one below.

```php
for ($i = 1; $i<=$messageCount; $i++) {
                $displayMessageCount = $i;
                echo $displayMessageCount;

                echo "
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo$displayMessageCount'>$date / $time - 1 new message from $fromUsername</button>
          <div id='demo$displayMessageCount' class='collapse'>
            $message 
          </div><br><br>";
            }
```

Now you have a separated variable that displays the count. `$messageCount` will now stay the same over every loop.
Hope this helps! If not, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer following all your recommendations

```
function newMessages() {

    global $connection;

    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT messageId, fromUsername, message, date, time FROM messages WHERE toUserId = ? AND messageRead = ? ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC")) {

         /* set variables */
         $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
         $messageRead = 'No';

         /* bind parameters for markers */
         $stmt->bind_param("is", $userId, $messageRead);

         /* execute query */
         $stmt->execute();

         /* bind result variables */
         $stmt->bind_result($messageId, $fromUsername, $message, $date, $time);

         /* fetch value */
         while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $messageId;     
         echo "
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo$messageId'>$date / $time - 1 new message from $fromUsername</button>
          <div id='demo$messageId' class='collapse'>
            $message 
          </div><br><br>";

         }

         /* close statement */
         $stmt->close();
    }

}
```

[image]